# Returning the sum of elements adjusted by the formula using recursion in code

Tags: java, recursion

Here we have a formula for elements of sequence: F[i] = 2 * F[i - 1] - cos(i), F[1] = 1.
In the task I should calculate the sum of N elements of the sequence using recursion. I can return the n-idexed element:

```
public double recursion(int n) {
    if (n == 1) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return (2 * recursion(n - 1) - Math.cos(n));    
}
```

but I don't know how to calculate the sum of that elements. How should I organize this process?

Comment: You could, for instance, add a parameter to where you would be accumulating the value of each step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first write a method called `f` that computes the function F[n], which you have done here. You should rename your `recursion` method to `f`.

```
private static double f(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (2 * f(n - 1) - Math.cos(n));
}
```

Then, you write another recursive method called `fsum` that calculates f(n) + f(n-1) + ... + f(1).

The base case is, of course, 1. When `n` is 1, `fsum` should return 1 as well, since f(1) is 1.

Otherwise, return f(n) + the sum of the rest of the f's. What's the sum of the rest of the f's? `fsum(n-1)`!

```
public static double fsum(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return f(n) + fsum(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Also, it would be good to use memorization here, since you are recalculating `f` for the same `n` many times here.